# drawing an excel chart from c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

please help me with this c# issue.
i have this code for adding a chart in excel, by selecting data from a table from c3 to f10 cells. i want to change the axis and i don't know how. now the elements from horizontal axis are from the rows in the table and on the vertical are elements from columns in the table. i want to pun the rows on the vertical axis and the columns on the horizontal axis. how can i do that? please help [CLOSED]

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts =(Excel.ChartObjects)excelWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(100, number*50, 300, 250);
Excel.Chart chart = myChart.Chart;
chartRange = excelWorksheet.get_Range("c3","f10");
chart.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

Comment: Hi Thezbx, have you tried anything so far? This could help us **help you** see where you're wrong.

Comment: pun: A joke exploiting the different possible meanings of a word or the fact that there are words that sound alike but have different meanings.

Comment: @sachin but can you pun rows? That is the question.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Some people can, but not me ;)

Comment: @sachin Damn I thought you were a punny guy...

Comment: excuse me, put rows**

Comment: i found the answer:  chart.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns); thank you